# Illustrator Adobe - Getting html coordinates from an illustrator file

Tags: html, coordinates, shapes, adobe-illustrator

I have an illustrator file and I need to get coordinates for the different shapes. The aim is to be able to click different parts of the image to link through to different URLs.

Please suggest how to achieve this

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's a matter of ignorance, but this does not sound like a programming-related question to me.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is use the Slice Tool to create smaller hot spots on your image.
http://www.pdesigner.net/Adobe_Illustrator_Tutorials/1_14_3_1.html <-- Slice Tool Tutorial

Then what you want to do is Select the Slice and then go to Object> Slice> Slice Options. Here you want to enter the url.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Illustrator/13.0/help.html?content=WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6361.html <-- How to set the Slice Options

After that you want to save and export your file for Web and Devices where you will choose the Images and HTML option.

Let me know if that works for you.